# Why is python accepting as True something that is not true?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

When the col and row are both 0, for some reason, the first two conditions of the conditions list are being accepted when they are not true. What is the reason behind this?

```
conditions = [
            # verifica ha espaco para ter um barco de 4
            row >= 0 and row <= 9, # problem here
            col >= 3 and col <= 9, # and here
            # verifica se posicao ja tem barco
            not (self.get_value(row, col).lower() == 'r' and\
            self.get_value(row, col - 1).lower() == 'm' and\
            self.get_value(row, col - 2).lower() == 'm' and\
            self.get_value(row, col - 3).lower() == 'l'),
            not (self.get_value(row, col).lower() == 'r' and\
            self.get_value(row, col - 1).lower() == 'm' and\
            self.get_value(row, col - 2).lower() == 'l'),
            not (self.get_value(row, col).lower() == 'r' and\
            self.get_value(row, col - 1).lower() == 'l'),
            not (self.get_value(row, col).lower() == 'c'),
            # verifica hints
            self.get_hint(row, self.size) >= 4,
            self.get_hint(self.size, row) >= 1,
            self.get_hint(self.size, row - 1) >= 1,
            self.get_hint(self.size, row - 2) >= 1,
            self.get_hint(self.size, row - 3) >= 1,
            # verifica nao ha barcos a direita
            self.get_value(row - 1, col + 2).lower() != 'r',
            self.get_value(row, col + 2).lower() != 'r',
            self.get_value(row + 1, col + 2).lower() != 'r',
            # verifica mar em cima
            self.get_value(row - 1, col + 1).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row - 1, col + 1) == '0' or self.get_value(row - 1, col + 1) == None,
            self.get_value(row - 1, col).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row - 1, col) == '0' or self.get_value(row - 1, col) == None,
            self.get_value(row - 1, col - 1).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 1) == '0' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 1) == None,          
            self.get_value(row - 1, col - 2).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 2) == '0' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 2) == None,
            self.get_value(row - 1, col - 3).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 3) == '0' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 3) == None,
            self.get_value(row - 1, col - 4).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 4) == '0' or self.get_value(row - 1, col - 4) == None,
            # verifica nao ha barcos em cima
            self.get_value(row - 2, col + 1).lower() != 't',
            self.get_value(row - 2, col).lower() != 't',
            self.get_value(row - 2, col - 1).lower() != 't',
            self.get_value(row - 2, col - 2).lower() != 't',
            self.get_value(row - 2, col - 3).lower() != 't',
            self.get_value(row - 2, col - 4).lower() != 't',
            # verifica mar em baixo
            self.get_value(row + 1, col + 1).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row + 1, col + 1) == '0' or self.get_value(row + 1, col + 1) == None,
            self.get_value(row + 1, col).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row + 1, col) == '0' or self.get_value(row + 1, col) == None,
            self.get_value(row + 1, col - 1).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 1) == '0' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 1) == None,          
            self.get_value(row + 1, col - 2).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 2) == '0' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 2) == None,
            self.get_value(row + 1, col - 3).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 3) == '0' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 3) == None,
            self.get_value(row + 1, col - 4).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 4) == '0' or self.get_value(row + 1, col - 4) == None,
            # verifica nao ha barcos em baixo
            self.get_value(row + 2, col + 1).lower() != 'b',
            self.get_value(row + 2, col).lower() != 'b',
            self.get_value(row + 2, col - 1).lower() != 'b',
            self.get_value(row + 2, col - 2).lower() != 'b',
            self.get_value(row + 2, col - 3).lower() != 'b',
            self.get_value(row + 2, col - 4).lower() != 'b',
            # verifica mar a esquerda e a direita
            self.get_value(row, col - 4).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row, col - 4) == '0' or self.get_value(row, col - 4) == None,
            self.get_value(row, col + 1).lower() == 'w' or self.get_value(row, col + 1) == '0' or self.get_value(row, col + 1) == None,
            # verifica nao ha barcos a esquerda
            self.get_value(row - 1, col - 5).lower() != 'l',
            self.get_value(row, col - 5).lower() != 'l',
            self.get_value(row + 1, col - 5).lower() != 'l',
            # verifica os valores nas posicoes a esquerda
            self.get_value(row, col).lower() == '0' or self.get_value(row, col).lower() == 'r',
            self.get_value(row, col - 1).lower() == '0' or self.get_value(row, col - 1).lower() == 'm',
            self.get_value(row, col - 2).lower() == '0' or self.get_value(row, col - 2).lower() == 'm',
            self.get_value(row, col - 3).lower() == '0' or self.get_value(row, col - 3).lower() == 'l'
        ]
        
        return all(conditions)
```

I tried putting more explicit conditions like col != 0, which should return instantly False, and it simply proceeds

Comment: Are you reassigning `row` and `col` after you create `conditions`? It's evaluating the conditions when you create the list, NOT when you call `all()`.

Comment: With both `row` and `col` set to `0`, I get `True, False` for the first two conditions. What do you get?

Comment: @Barmar I did not include in the block of code but this is a function that is defined as: "def verify_4_horizontal(self, row: int, col: int) -> bool:", and whats calling this function is something like "self.verify_4_horizontal(0, 0)" do I still need to reassign the variables?

Comment: @quamrana it should be "True, False" but it is proceding to the following conditions as if it was not False. Maybe, it will check all the conditions even if some return False and then fail the all()

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://ideone.com/Z60PRh

Comment: @Barmar my code is like "p = [None, 1]
col = 0
conditions = [
    (col == 1),
    p[row] >= 0,
    ]
if all(conditions): print("nope")" Im aware that you cant compare None but it should only compare None if the first condition is True

Comment: There's no short-circuiting when creating a list.

Comment: All the comparisons are done when assigning to `conditions`, not when you call `all(conditions)`.

Comment: @Barmar I see, then I will first check if the first two conditions apply outside the list. Thanks